# Query date between periods

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

So, i'm trying to query all the data between 2 dates. The date field on my mysql table is at this format: (dd-mm-yyy). So, i'm using php for this.

I made something Like this:

```
    SELECT *
FROM `sells`
WHERE date
BETWEEN '01-01-2013'
AND '04-02-2014'
```

of course this dates will be variables, but for test on phpmyadmin i didnt achieve the expected result. It gives me all the data ON this dates, let me show.

```
03-01-2014      
03-01-2014  
03-01-2014      
01-02-2014      
01-02-2014          
03-02-2014      
03-02-2014      
03-02-2014 
03-02-2014
```

And of course, all the other datas, but its irrelevant.

I want to bring all the data between a period of dates, how can i fix this error?

Thanks.

Added show table.
Its on my native language, so. (its a domestic system, for my home business

```
CREATE TABLE `vendas` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `id_cliente` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `cliente` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
 `produto` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
 `quantidade` int(255) NOT NULL,
 `valor` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
 `total` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
 `metodo` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
 `data` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
 `status` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `data_pagamento` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=103 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_spanish_ci
```

Comment: Did u try Try date> and date< ??

Comment: That won't help them because their dates are stored as strings in a non-standard format, not dates.

Comment: If you store the date in YYYY-MM-DD even as a string it will still allow you to select using a between. But like this will never work, just put all the dates in a column in a spreadsheet and sort that column ASC. it will return all the results grouped together starting with all the 01's, 02's, 03's etc regardless of the date!

Comment: @Matheus can you add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE sells;` output, so we are sure about the column definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what happens when you store your dates as strings instead of as dates. You get query hell.

You will need to convert your string dates into the proper format and then change your search criteria to also be in the proper date format (YYYY-MM-DD):

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date, "%d-%m-%Y")
BETWEEN '2013-01-01'
AND '2014-02-04'
```

Comment: They say they are in dd-mm-yyyy format in their question

Comment: on my table i have storage date in dd-mm-yyyy format, it will works? i tryied and doesnt..

Answer (score -2):

Try this -

```
SELECT *
FROM `sells`
WHERE  DATE_FORMAT(<your column name>,'%m-%d-%Y') >= '01-01-2013'
and DATE_FORMAT(<your column name>,'%m-%d-%Y') <= '04-02-2014';
```

And this will also work --

```
SELECT *
    FROM `sells`
    WHERE <your column name> between DATE_FORMAT('01-01-2013','%m-%d-%Y')  
    and DATE_FORMAT('04-02-2014','%m-%d-%Y');
```

Comment: may i know the reason for down vote.. this is 100% working code

Comment: Even if `date` has a `DATE` datatype (and is not stored as string as the OP states), this query would still return dates out of the range, like `'01-01-2068`.

Comment: date is his table's column name if column name is changed then this query will work fine